# convert date unix to timestamp

Tags: sql, datetime, informix, epoch

I want to convert type date unix to timestamp in Informix.
My column date1 contains values as 1598915961, 1598911249, 1598911255...

**expected output: 2020-02-13 15:00:00**

How should I do it, please?

Comment: See also [Informix FROM_UNIXTIME alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55600549/15168).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Informix, you can use [`dbinfo()`  and `'utc_to_datetime'`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1495.htm):

```
select dbinfo('utc_to_datetime', myepoch)
```

Comment: my epoch is it the column ? @GMB

Comment: @Jappa: yes, indeed.

Comment: @Jappa: if your column is called `nb1` in table `table1`, then: `select dbinfo('utc_to_datetime', nb1) from table1`

Comment: `DBINFO(‘utc_to_datetime’, table1.nb1)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you can add the seconds to the date `'1970-01-01'`.  I don't have Informix on-hand, but the syntax is something like this:

```
select datetime('1970-01-01') + interval date1 second
```

Comment: The general idea is correct but Informix throws a number of spanners into the works. The most significant is that it limits the number of seconds that can be added in a single operation to 999,999,999.  See [Informix FROM_UNIXTIME alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55600549/15168).